# Capturing a static variable by reference in a C++11 lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

## Main question

I'm trying to compile the following code with GCC 4.7.2:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo() {
    static int bar;
    return [&bar] () { return bar++; } (); // lambda capturing by reference
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And it seems that is not going well, as the output is this one:

```
$p2.cpp: In function ‘int foo()’:
$p2.cpp:6:14: warning: capture of variable ‘bar’ with non-automatic storage duration [enabled by default]
$p2.cpp:4:16: note: ‘int bar’ declared here
```

So, my first question would be:

**Is this a failure of GCC, or the code is not legit C++11? Is this fixed in any recent version of GCC?**

## Using the trick in a shared_ptr factory

I consider to build an artifact based on this principle but using a non-literal static variable. This artifact is meant to be a factory of shared_ptr< T > objects, which avoid the creation of new T objects when you just need a duplicate shared_ptr container for the same instance.

This artifact would look like:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> create(std::string name) {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string,std::weak_ptr<Foo>> registry;

    if (auto it = registry.find(name) != registry.end())
        return registry[name].lock();

    auto b = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(
        new Foo(name), 
        [&registry] (Foo* p) {
            registry.erase(p->getName());
            delete p;
        });

    registry.emplace(name,b);
    return b;
}
```

As far as I know, if the GCC issue discussed before is not a problem in terms of C++11 conformance, this artifact shouldn't be an issue either. The only thing to take care by using this hack, is to not set the resulting shared_ptr< T > object to any global object which could be destructed after the static variable.

**Am I right about this?**

Comment: Compiles and runs fine on g++ 4.6.3

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Why are you even trying to capture `bar`? It's static. You don't need to capture it at all. Only automatic variables need capturing. Clang throws a hard error on your code, not just a warning. And if you simply remove the `&bar` from your lambda capture, then the code works perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>

int foo() {
    static int bar;
    return [] () { return bar++; } (); // lambda capturing by reference
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: @Troy: Probably a bug in g++ 4.6.3 then.

Comment: Sweet, thought it wasn't in the scope in this circunstance, thanks.

Comment: I am getting the same warning with an `extern` global variable (not marked `static`). Do I need to capture it?

Comment: if I only wanna capture bar by value? While I put bar in [bar], the compiler meet error

Answer (score 16):

Per the standard, you can only capture variables with automatic storage duration (or `this`, which is mentioned as explicitly capturable).

So, no, you can't do that as per the standard (or, to answer your first question, that is not valid C++ 11 and is not a compiler bug)

> 5.1.1/2 A name in the lambda-capture shall be in scope in the context of the lambda expression, and shall be this or refer to a local
>   variable or reference with automatic storage duration.

EDIT: And, as Kevin mentioned, you don't even need to capture a local `static` anyways.

Comment: Why is this a requirement? What is the danger in capturing a non-auto variable?