# Boost::thread: Syntax confusion in lambda captures

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, lambda

I have included `boost::thread.hpp` on some of my header file and I have this code in one of `class` structures I made:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<void ()> XEvent;

enum X_Widget_Type
{
    XW_BUTTON,
    XW_TEXTBOX,
    XW_CHECK_BOX,
    XW_COMBO_BOX
};
//XWidget.h
class XWidget
{
public:
    XWidget(const char *name, const Rect& rect, X_Widget_Type type, const HWND parent) :

     onClick(nullptr)
    ,id(++X_ID_COUNTER)
    {
        int flags = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP;
        char widget_name[128];

        switch (type)
        {
        case XW_BUTTON:
            flags |= BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON;
            strcpy(widget_name, "BUTTON");
            break;
        case XW_TEXTBOX:
            flags |= ES_USER_PRESENT;
            strcpy(widget_name, "EDIT");
            break;
        case XW_CHECK_BOX:
            flags |= BS_AUTOCHECKBOX;
            strcpy(widget_name, "BUTTON");
            break;
        case XW_COMBO_BOX:
            flags |= CBS_DROPDOWN;
            strcpy(widget_name, "COMBOBOX");
        }

        handle = CreateWindowEx(
            WS_EX_STATICEDGE,
            widget_name, name,
            flags,
            rect.x, rect.y,
            rect.width, rect.height,
            parent, (HMENU)getID(),
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);
    }

    XEvent onClick;

private:
    int XWidget::X_ID_COUNTER;
}

//XCheckbox.h
class XCheckbox :
    public XWidget
{
    XCheckbox(const char *name, const Rect& rect, const HWND parent) :
        XWidget(name, rect, XW_CHECK_BOX, parent) { }
    ...
}

//main.cpp

bool cheat1 = false;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    CWin app("win32app", nCmdShow);
    ...

    XCheckbox chkbox("checkbox", {0, 0, 50, 22}, app.getHandle());

    XCheckbox.onClick =
    [chkbox, app, &cheat1] //  <--this doesn't compile when I include `boost::thread.hpp` ?
    {
        ...
    };

    ...
}
```

Now, when I include `boost::thread.hpp`, it doesn't compile and I got these bunch of errors and warnings:

```
||=== Build: Debug in rasman (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\CPP\rasman\src\main.cpp||In function 'int WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)':|
D:\CPP\rasman\src\main.cpp|85|warning: capture of variable 'cheat1' with non-automatic storage duration [enabled by default]|
D:\CPP\rasman\src\main.cpp|43|note: 'bool cheat1' declared here|
D:\CPP\rasman\src\main.cpp|108|warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]|
d:\cb\codeblocks\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h||In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = boost::thread; _Args = {const boost::thread&}]':|
d:\cb\codeblocks\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h|75|required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const boost::thread*, std::vector<boost::thread> >; _ForwardIterator = boost::thread*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'|
d:\cb\codeblocks\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h|117|required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const boost::thread*, std::vector<boost::thread> >; _ForwardIterator = boost::thread*]'|
d:\cb\codeblocks\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h|258|required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const boost::thread*, std::vector<boost::thread> >; _ForwardIterator = boost::thread*; _Tp = boost::thread]'|
d:\cb\codeblocks\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h|316|required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = boost::thread; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::thread>]'|
include\cwin.h|25|required from here|
d:\cb\codeblocks\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h|75|error: use of deleted function 'boost::thread::thread(const boost::thread&)'|
D:\cb\boost_1_55_0\boost\thread\detail\thread.hpp|165|error: declared here|
D:\cb\boost_1_55_0\boost\thread\detail\delete.hpp|20|note: in definition of macro 'BOOST_THREAD_DELETE_COPY_CTOR'|
D:\cb\boost_1_55_0\boost\thread\detail\move.hpp|231|note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_THREAD_NO_COPYABLE'|
D:\cb\boost_1_55_0\boost\thread\detail\thread.hpp|165|note: in expansion of macro 'BOOST_THREAD_MOVABLE_ONLY'|
D:\cb\boost_1_55_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp|222|warning: 'boost::system::posix_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
D:\cb\boost_1_55_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp|223|warning: 'boost::system::errno_ecat' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
D:\cb\boost_1_55_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp|224|warning: 'boost::system::native_ecat' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 11 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 9 second(s)) ===|
```

but if I excluded the `boost::thread.hpp`, it compiles fine?

What could be I'm missing here? What's the problem?

**Update:**

The reason I want to include `boost::thread.hpp` is because of this functions

```
void createThread(std::function<void ()> thread_function)
{
    threads.push_back(boost::thread(thread_function));
}
```

or

```
template<typename T>
void createThread(T thread_function)
{
    threads.push_back(boost::thread(thread_function));
}
```

Comment: You're trying to copy a `boost::thread` somehow. Considering this code makes no mention of one, it's hard to tell how.

Comment: @chris Is it the lambda function that the compiler auto-translate it into typeof `boost::thread` ?

Comment: Lambdas have nothing to do with `boost::thread`. The language has no idea that Boost, let alone its thread class, exists. Please produce an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @chris Please see my updates and please tell if this qualifies a bit in [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the strange `boost::thread` errors you are getting, the issue lies with the attempt to pass a reference to a statics variable to a lambda function, which is not possible (see this question for more info on why: [Capturing a static variable by reference in a C++11 lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827855/capturing-a-static-variable-by-reference-in-a-c11-lambda)).

The long and short of t is that you don't need to pass `cheat1` to the lambda function beacuse `cheat1` is already accessible.  Remove the `&cheat1` argument to the lambda and access the variable normally.

Comment: I only need to get rid off in compile error, what's the proper syntax? Anyway, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Where you have `[chkbox, app, &cheat1]`, replace it with `[chkbox, app]`.  Alternatively you could just replace it with `[&]` which captures all in-scope variables by reference.

Comment: Okay, okay.. What's should I do now to get this compile?

Comment: If you are still getting the boost errors, just eliminate the `#include <boost/thread.hpp>` line.  From what I can see there is no reason for it based on the source code that was provided.

Comment: I want to use `boost/thread.hpp` that is why I am including it. Please see my update. Thanks