# fill vector with random elements

Tags: c++, random, lambda, stl

Why my lambda doesn't put elements in vector?

```
void generate_N_numbers_in_the_vector(std::vector<int> &vec, int &M,
                                      const int &N) {
  std::random_device rand;
  static std::mt19937 gen(rand());
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, M);
  vec.reserve(N);

  std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), []() { return distribution(gen); });

  for (auto elem : vec) std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Because it is empty. Use `.resize()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choice between vector::resize() and vector::reserve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve)

Comment: In modern C++ you better return that vector rather than pass it by reference - due to move semantics it is not less efficient but much more readable. For example it may solve your issue as a side effect (you probably would use proper ctor with size)

Comment: @Slava, it can be less efficient if this function is called repeatedly on the same vector.

Comment: @Evg then subject to the question should be "add random elements to a vector" instead of "fill vector..."

Answer (score 4):

When you use `reserve` the number of elements in the vector does not increase. That means that the difference between `begin(vec)` and `end(vec)` is 0 (or whatever the size of your vector was at the start). There are two possibilities:

```cpp
vec.resize(N);
std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](){return distribution(gen);});
// or
vec.reserve(N); // Not necessary but sensible.
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vec), N, [](){return distribution(gen);});
```

Comment: [Can't capture a static variable in a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45930423)

Comment: "That means that the difference between begin(vec) and end(vec) is 0" How do you know this?...

Comment: @Ayxan *When you use reserve the number of elements in the vector does not increase.*

Comment: @NathanOliver how do you know the vector was empty to begin with?

Comment: From the name of the of the function, I assume OP wants the vector to have n random numbers. In which case your second suggestion is outright wrong.

Comment: @Ayxan Because if it was, the user would be complaining that it only generated some numbers.

Comment: Thx @Evg I missed the static. I already wondered why OPs code even compiles.

Comment: In the second solution I suggest you clear it first. The function name suggests it should be cleared.

Comment: @NathanOliver there could be other reasons. For instance, `std::cout` could have already failed.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector::reserve` only *reserves* space, meaning increases the capacity, not the size. Use `std::vector::resize` instead to change the vector's size.